# Setting value for inner method in php unit

Tags: php, phpunit

I can not set value for inner method when I try to test. Here I have written a sample class. I have created mock object for same class but does not effect.

```
class A
{
    public function OneTest()
    {
        if($this->TwoTest()){
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function TwoTest()
    {
        // return somethings
    }
}
```

I am new at phpunit test writing. if some one expert help me that good for me. I want to test this method. I have tried with:

```
class ATest  extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $helper = new testOne();

        // trying to set TwoTest() method value but does not effect.
        $mock = $this->createMock(A::class);
        $mock->method("TwoTest")
             ->willReturn(true);

        $this->assertTrue($helper->OneTest();
    }
}
```

Actually I do not know how to use my mocking method result. My actual implementation in twoTest method contains some db related code. I do not want to run db code in testing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close with your mock. What you want to do is called partial mocking. This is done by creating a mock of `A` with only `TwoTest` being mocked, i.e. it will now always return true and never actually call the real code inside the original implementation in `A`, whereas all other methods still act as before. Therefore calling `$mock->OneTest()` should return the expected result. Since you make both calls on the (partially) mocked instance, you won't need `$helper`. So your test would probably look something like this:

```
public function testOneWhenTwoTestReturnsTrue()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(A::class)
        ->setMethods(["TwoTest"])
        ->getMock();
    $mock->method("TwoTest")
         ->willReturn(true);

    $this->assertTrue($mock->OneTest();
}
```

Notice that I use `getMockBuilder()` instead of just `createMock()` and `setMethods()` is what we need for your test. We only overwrite the one method we want to mock, the rest will behave as defined in the original class. To quote the docs:

> setMethods(array $methods) can be called on the Mock Builder object to specify the methods that are to be replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. If you call setMethods(null), then no methods will be replaced.